# Can't create ViewModel from ViewModelProvider

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

Recently, I try to develop the app which have the same view in different modules so I tried  to re-use ViewModel.
Here is viewModel class

```
class ChooseDataViewModel<T: DataSelectable>(application: Application) :
    AndroidViewModel(application) {
    val title = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private val mData = MutableLiveData<List<T>>() }
class ClassA: DataSelectable{}
class ClassB: DataSelectable{}
```

In fragment i tried to create viewModel with Data type as ClassB by this method:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(navBackStackEntry).get(ChooseDataViewModel::class.java)
```

But the compiler shows error message

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
ChooseDataViewModel<T>?
Found:
ChooseDataViewModel<*>
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please update your ViewModel class like below.

```
class ChooseDataViewModel(application: Application) :
    AndroidViewModel(application) {
    val title = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private val mData = MutableLiveData<List<DataSelectable>>() }
```

I hope it's helpful to you!

Comment: Thank you bro. I added more text for the question, could you help me to check the question again.